# Mouse wheel rotates instead of zooming in

Tags: modeling

My mouse wheel is suddenly rotating around an object instead of zooming in. What hotkey did I accidentally press, and how do I get it to zoom again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That generally happens if you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Scroll Wheel</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Scroll Wheel</kbd> by default.

The fact that it is doing it by default may mean that you either changed the keyboard shortcuts in Blender preferences, you have a stuck key in your keyboard, or something else is interfering with which key presses are being sent to Blender.

As far as I know there is no keyboard shortcut to permanently set this behavior by default.

Check what hardware is currently plugged into Blender. Some input devices like drawing tablets, pads, game controllers or 3D Mouse may erroneously send keystrokes or simulate keypresses that confuse Blender or alter its behavior. if in doubt disconnect them all, restart Blender and see if behavior changes.

Comment: I was using a Wacom tablet, which I unplugged. That's when the mouse wheel started rotating instead of zooming. I rebooted blender and now everything works as it's supposed to! So technically, it was a stuck key, if you consider a tablet to be an additional set of keys.

Comment: Ah I see, possibly some input conflict then.

Answer (score 0):

You can always reload factory settings to start fresh....